Calculo con separador de decimales
hola a todos espero estén bien... tengo este código el cual como hago para que se haga el calculo con separador de decimales (por ejemplo ca en Colombia son 3) por ejemplo 1.300
También que el campo Valor Unitario al ir escribiendo el valor este se vaya separando automáticamente con el separador  (.)
el ejemplo va calculando la cantidad y el valor pero tengo un problema necesito que al escribir el valor Unitario el campo separe los decimales (3) pues acá en Colombia se usa así en pesos por ejemplo 3.000
que en el campo que va mostrando el valor igual salga con decimales por ejemplo al poner cantidad 2 x 1.500 en este salga 3.000
y en el campo Total que es la suma igual salga el valor con el punto separador de decimales.


    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" id="bootstrap-css">
    <script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row clearfix">
        <div class="col-md-12">
          <table class="table table-bordered table-hover" id="tab_logic">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th class="text-center"> # </th>
                <th class="text-center"> Item </th>
                <th class="text-center"> Cant </th>
                <th class="text-center"> Valor Unitario</th>
                <th class="text-center"> Valor</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              <tr id='addr0'>
                <td>1</td>
                <td><input type="text" name='product[]'  placeholder='' class="form-control"/></td>
                <td><input type="number" name='qty[]' placeholder='' class="form-control qty" step="0" min="0"/></td>
                <td><input type="number" name='price[]' placeholder='' class="form-control price" step="0" min="0"/></td>
                <td><input type="number" name='total[]' placeholder='' class="form-control total" readonly/></td>
              </tr>
              <tr id='addr1'></tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row clearfix">
        <div class="col-md-12">
          <button id="add_row" class="btn btn-default pull-left">+ Item</button>
          <button id='delete_row' class="pull-right btn btn-default">- Item</button>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row clearfix" style="margin-top:20px">
        <div class="pull-right col-md-4">
          <table class="table table-bordered table-hover" id="tab_logic_total">
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <th class="text-center">Total</th>
                <td class="text-center"><input type="number" name='sub_total' placeholder='' class="form-control" id="sub_total" readonly/></td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var i=1;
        $("#add_row").click(function(){b=i-1;
            $('#addr'+i).html($('#addr'+b).html()).find('td:first-child').html(i+1);
            $('#tab_logic').append('<tr id="addr'+(i+1)+'"></tr>');
            i++; 
        });
        $("#delete_row").click(function(){
            if(i>1){
            $("#addr"+(i-1)).html('');
            i--;
            }
            calc();
        });
        
        $('#tab_logic tbody').on('keyup change',function(){
            calc();
        });
        $('#tax').on('keyup change',function(){
            calc_total();
        });
        
    
    });
    
    function calc()
    {
        $('#tab_logic tbody tr').each(function(i, element) {
            var html = $(this).html();
            if(html!='')
            {
                var qty = $(this).find('.qty').val();
                var price = $(this).find('.price').val();
                $(this).find('.total').val(qty*price);
                
                calc_total();
            }
        });
    }
    
    function calc_total()
    {
        total=0;
        $('.total').each(function() {
            total += parseInt($(this).val());
        });
        $('#sub_total').val(total.toFixed(0));
        tax_sum=total/100*$('#tax').val();
        $('#tax_amount').val(tax_sum.toFixed(0));
        $('#total_amount').val((tax_sum+total).toFixed(0));
    }
    </script>




Creo que esas cuestiones hay que solucionarlas a mano. Convertir los números al formato esperado por parseFloat. Sustituir la coma por punto y los divisores decimales por nada.

se podria hacer si se usa tolocalestring para formatear los valores y agregar un controlador input mientras se escribe en campo de "valor unitario" y se formatee automaticamente el valor con separadores de miles. y exactamente tambien como se menciona en la respuesta anterior con parsefloat
son detallitos pero varios tratare de expplicarlo:

al principio no hay formateo mientras se escribe el valor unitario, se puede modificar agregando un input para que se formatee el valor al estilo colombiano con separadores de miles usando tolocalestring
los valores qty y precio se multiplican directamente sin tomar en cuenta el formato con separador de miles, se tiene que eliminar el punto de los valores de precio antes de hacer la mukltiplicacion y luego se vuelve a formatear el total calculado con el tolocalstring colombiano
se estan sumando los valores de cada fila directamente sin formateo y pues se muestra el resultado sin separadores de miles
ahora el valor unitario y el total lo pones de tipo number y eso hace que no se incluya puntos como separadores de miles, cambialos a tipo text

algo asi quedaria con los cambios y ajustes:
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" id="bootstrap-css">
<script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row clearfix">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <table class="table table-bordered table-hover" id="tab_logic">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th class="text-center"> # </th>
            <th class="text-center"> Item </th>
            <th class="text-center"> Cant </th>
            <th class="text-center"> Valor Unitario</th>
            <th class="text-center"> Valor</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr id='addr0'>
            <td>1</td>
            <td><input type="text" name='product[]'  placeholder='' class="form-control"/></td>
            <td><input type="number" name='qty[]' placeholder='' class="form-control qty" step="0" min="0"/></td>
            <td><input type="text" name='price[]' placeholder='' class="form-control price" step="0" min="0"/></td>
            <td><input type="text" name='total[]' placeholder='' class="form-control total" readonly/></td>
          </tr>
          <tr id='addr1'></tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row clearfix">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <button id="add_row" class="btn btn-default pull-left">+ Item</button>
      <button id='delete_row' class="pull-right btn btn-default">- Item</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row clearfix" style="margin-top:20px">
    <div class="pull-right col-md-4">
      <table class="table table-bordered table-hover" id="tab_logic_total">
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <th class="text-center">Total</th>
            <td class="text-center"><input type="text" name='sub_total' placeholder='' class="form-control" id="sub_total" readonly/></td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    var i=1;
    $("#add_row").click(function(){b=i-1;
        $('#addr'+i).html($('#addr'+b).html()).find('td:first-child').html(i+1);
        $('#tab_logic').append('<tr id="addr'+(i+1)+''></tr>');
        i++; 
    });
    $("#delete_row").click(function(){
        if(i>1){
        $("#addr"+(i-1)).html('');
        i--;
        }
        calc();
    });
    
    $('#tab_logic tbody').on('keyup change',function(){
        calc();
    });
    $('#tax').on('keyup change',function(){
        calc_total();
    });
    
    $(document).on('input', '.price', function() {
        let inputVal = $(this).val().replace(/\./g, '');
        if(inputVal !== ''){
            let formattedVal = parseFloat(inputVal).toLocaleString('es-CO');
            $(this).val(formattedVal);
        }
    });
});

function calc()
{
    $('#tab_logic tbody tr').each(function(i, element) {
        var html = $(this).html();
        if(html!='')
        {
            var qty = parseFloat($(this).find('.qty').val());
            var price = parseFloat($(this).find('.price').val().replace(/\./g, ''));
            var total = qty * price;
            $(this).find('.total').val(total.toLocaleString('es-CO'));
            
            calc_total();
        }
    });
}
function calc_total()
{
    var total = 0;
    $('.total').each(function() {
        var val = parseFloat($(this).val().replace(/\./g, ''));
        total += val;
    });
    $('#sub_total').val(total.toLocaleString('es-CO'));
}
</script>

espero que sea lo que buscas, correlo y si no funciona lo modificamos.. si algo no comprendes en alguna linea vamos a tratar de describir como funciona o porqye.. saludos

Mil gracia spor responder pero me sale un error en la linea 54.. algo dentro del script esta mal:    $('#tab_logic').append('<tr id="addr'+(i+1)+''>');

el error es por una comilla $('#tab_logic').append('');

Hola.. pensé que solucionando esa linea se solucionaba.. aun sigue sin funcionar... :(

entonces es problema de concatenacion y espacios: $('#tab_logic').append('');

Te sugiero las siguientes modificaciones:

Al borrar una fila, llamar a calc_total() (no tiene sentido llamar a calc())

Detectar cuando ingresen un valor solo en los input type="number". Así:
$('#tab_logic tbody').on('input', 'input[type="number"]', function(evt) {


Modificar la función calc para que solo calcule el total de la fila donde se está modificando valores.

Utilizar toFixed para obtener el total con 3 decimales
$tr.find('.total').val((qty * price).toFixed(3));


Utilizar parseFloat para obtener el valor guardado en cada input.total
total += parseFloat($(this).val());


[Observación] Al modificar el valor del elemento #tax, no es necesario recalcular el subtotal. Podes crear una nueva funciona para que haga solo ese cálculo.


Ejemplo:
Realizando todas las modificaciones mencionadas anteriormente, tu código podría quedar así:


$(document).ready(function() {
  var i = 1;
  
  // Add
  $("#add_row").click(function() {
    b = i - 1;
    $('#addr' + i).html($('#addr' + b).html()).find('td:first-child').html(i + 1);
    $('#tab_logic').append('<tr id="addr' + (i + 1) + '"></tr>');
    i++;
  });
  
  // Delete
  $("#delete_row").click(function() {
    if (i > 1) {
      $("#addr" + (i - 1)).html('');
      i--;
    }
    calc_total();
  });

  // On input value change
  $('#tab_logic tbody').on('input', 'input[type="number"]', function(evt) {
    calc($(evt.currentTarget).closest('tr'));
  });
  
  $('#tax').on('input', function() {
    calc_total();
  });


});

// Calcular total de la fila
function calc($tr) {
  var qty = $tr.find('.qty').val();
  var price = $tr.find('.price').val();
      
  // Total con 3 decimales
  $tr.find('.total').val((qty * price).toFixed(3));

  calc_total();
}

function calc_total() {
  var total = 0;
  $('#tab_logic .total').each(function() {
    // Obtener el valor como float
    total += parseFloat($(this).val());
  });
  // Dar formato con 3 decimales
  $('#sub_total').val(total.toFixed(3));
  
  // Esto podría estar en otra función
  tax_sum = total / 100 * $('#tax').val();
  $('#tax_amount').val(tax_sum.toFixed(0));
  $('#total_amount').val((tax_sum + total).toFixed(0));
}
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" id="bootstrap-css">
<script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row clearfix">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <table class="table table-bordered table-hover" id="tab_logic">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th class="text-center"> # </th>
            <th class="text-center"> Item </th>
            <th class="text-center"> Cant </th>
            <th class="text-center"> Valor Unitario</th>
            <th class="text-center"> Valor</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr id='addr0'>
            <td>1</td>
            <td><input type="text" name='product[]' placeholder='' class="form-control" /></td>
            <td><input type="number" name='qty[]' placeholder='' class="form-control qty" step="0" min="0" /></td>
            <td><input type="number" name='price[]' placeholder='' class="form-control price" step="0" min="0" /></td>
            <td><input type="number" name='total[]' placeholder='' class="form-control total" readonly/></td>
          </tr>
          <tr id='addr1'></tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row clearfix">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <button id="add_row" class="btn btn-default pull-left">+ Item</button>
      <button id='delete_row' class="pull-right btn btn-default">- Item</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row clearfix" style="margin-top:20px">
    <div class="pull-right col-md-4">
      <table class="table table-bordered table-hover" id="tab_logic_total">
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <th class="text-center">Total</th>
            <td class="text-center"><input type="number" name='sub_total' placeholder='' class="form-control" id="sub_total" readonly/></td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>



